# Mutating Error , How to solve it

Tags: oracle, trigger, plsql, insert

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LOAN_RP
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON FUND_DISBURSE
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
V_FA          FUND_DISBURSE.FUND_AMT%TYPE;
V_RC          NUMBER (10);
V_AC          FUND_DISBURSE.AREA_CODE%TYPE;
V_BC          FUND_DISBURSE.BRANCH_CODE%TYPE;
V_CC          FUND_DISBURSE.COMP_CODE%TYPE;
V_DN          FUND_DISBURSE.DAFA_NO%TYPE;
V_PRN         NUMBER (15,2);
V_SC          NUMBER (15,2);
V_INSN        NUMBER (2) :=0;
V_INSD        FUND_DISBURSE.DISBURSE_DATE%TYPE;
V_RAMT        NUMBER (15,2);
BEGIN
select AREA_CODE, BRANCH_CODE, COMP_CODE,DAFA_NO,DISBURSE_DATE,FUND_AMT
into 
V_AC,V_BC,V_CC,V_DN,V_INSD,V_FA
from FUND_DISBURSE
WHERE AREA_CODE = :NEW.AREA_CODE
and BRANCH_CODE = :NEW.BRANCH_CODE
and COMP_CODE = :NEW.COMP_CODE
and DAFA_NO = :NEW.DAFA_NO
AND DISBURSE_DATE =:NEW.DISBURSE_DATE
AND FUND_AMT = :NEW.FUND_AMT;
V_RAMT := V_FA*1.13;
V_INSD := (V_INSD-7) + 14;
for i in 1..50 loop
V_INSD := V_INSD+7;
V_RC := V_FA/1000*25;
V_PRN := V_RC/1.13;
V_SC := V_RC - V_PRN;
V_INSN := V_INSN + 1;
V_RAMT := V_RAMT - V_RC;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_RC);
INSERT INTO F_REPAY_SCHEDULE (AREA_CODE,BRANCH_CODE, COMP_CODE,     
DAFA_NO,INSTALL_NO,INSTALL_DATE,INSTALL_AMT, PRN_AMT, SC_AMT)  
VALUES (:new.area_code,:new.branch_code,:new.comp_code,:new.dafa_no,V_INSN, V_INSD,   
V_RC,    
V_PRN,V_SC );
EXIT WHEN V_RAMT < V_RC;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**Trigger complied, but can not insert any record. 
 table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it**

How can I solve it. Please suggest.

**Sorry again. Thanks to ***mat and all*** for helping me**.
I have understood. 
Here my new code after correction.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LOAN_RP
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON FUND_DISBURSE
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
V_RC          NUMBER (10);
V_PRN         NUMBER (15,2);
V_SC          NUMBER (15,2);
V_INSN        NUMBER (2) :=0;
V_RAMT        NUMBER (15,2);
v_insd        date;
BEGIN
V_RAMT := :NEW.FUND_AMT*1.13;
V_INSD := (:NEW.DISBURSE_DATE -7 ) + 14;
LOOP
V_INSD := V_INSD+7;
V_RC   := :NEW.FUND_AMT/1000*25;
V_PRN  := V_RC/1.13;
V_SC   := V_RC - V_PRN;
V_INSN := V_INSN + 1;
V_RAMT := V_RAMT - V_RC;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_RC);
INSERT INTO F_REPAY_SCHEDULE (AREA_CODE,BRANCH_CODE, COMP_CODE,  
DAFA_NO,INSTALL_NO,INSTALL_DATE,INSTALL_AMT, PRN_AMT, SC_AMT) 
VALUES (:new.area_code,:new.branch_code,:new.comp_code,:new.dafa_no,V_INSN, V_INSD,  
V_RC, V_PRN,V_SC);
EXIT WHEN V_RAMT < V_RC;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: What's the purpose of that select on `fund_disburse`? You already have the data in `:new`.

Comment: I want to make a repayment schedule getting data from the fund disburse table. When I will insert a row/records in a fund disburse table that  will create a different repayment schedule on the r_repay_schedule table for every row on fund_disburse table. 
Here's my primary key on Fund_disburse table (area_code, branch_code, comp_code, dafa_no) and that is references on R_repay_schedule as Foreign Key

Comment: Again, what's the purpose for that select on `fund_disburse`? You've got the whole PK, so you already have the data in `:new`.

Comment: Thanks Mat. I have done it. Thanks for suggestion. Sorry again. I give my new code after my question.

Answer (score -2):

the code erro ORA-04091 is relative the transaction. In a trigger you dont can execute select, unless you declare a new transacation with clause PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION.

remember to run a commit or rollback to finalize transaction on the trigger.

Comment: Bad advice. Just don't select from the mutating table in your trigger at all.

Comment: A trigger belongs to DML operation, thus `commit` or `rollback` must not be done inside a trigger.